# Switching JIT debuggers?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, delphi, debugging

When you have to maintain different projects with different IDEs, it often makes sense to install them on the same Windows machine.

For instance, mix Visual Studio and Delphi, or various versions of Delphi on the same system (I'm sure others have even different combinations).

One of the things you will find there is that the latest tool installs itself as JIT debugger: the just-in-time debugger that fires when an app crashes.

Depending in which tool and version that app crashed (sometimes you cannot reproduce bugs when running inside the debugger, for instance in case of a Heisenbug), you want to select the debugger in advance.

How can you do that?

Comment: JIT debugger is set in registry, ugly - but your applications can change it on the start. Though that would not help when running several diferent apps in parallel

Comment: To set up the Delphi IDE, instead of installing multiple versions, the information in [this article](http://support.codegear.com/article/36747) may help. (It's a codegear.com link, but it loads as of the time I'm writing this text.) The article refers to older versions of Delphi, but can be easily updated to work with newer versions.

Comment: Thanks, this is the Embarcadero link that should live longer: http://support.embarcadero.com/article/36747

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write a simple application that would launch the debugger you want in case of an application crash.

Register your app in

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug
```

In case of an 64bit OS, also to the following key

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug
```

add/modify the string named `Debugger` with value:

```
"C:..\Win32\Debug\Project1.exe" %ld %ld
```

A very simple application:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComboBox1.Items.Add('BDS 16');
  ComboBox1.Items.Add('BDS 15');
  ComboBox1.Items.Add('WinDbg');
  ComboBox1.Items.Add('VS');
  // etc..
  ComboBox1.ItemIndex := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  proc: THandle;
begin
  Assert(ParamCount >= 2);
  proc := OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, False, StrToInt(ParamStr(1)));
  case ComboBox1.ItemIndex of
    0: ShellExecute(0, '', 'C:\..\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\bds.exe',
          PChar(Format('/attach:%s;%s', [ParamStr(1), ParamStr(2)])), '',
          SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    1 : // etc..
    2: ShellExecute(0, '', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\..\windbg.exe',
          PChar(Format('-p %s -e %s -g', [ParamStr(1), ParamStr(2)])), '',
          SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    3: ShellExecute(0, '', 'C:\Windows\system32\VSJitDebugger.exe',
          PChar(Format('-p %s -e %s', [ParamStr(1), ParamStr(2)])), '',
          SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    //..
  end;
  if Bool(proc) then begin
    WaitForSingleObject(proc, INFINITE);
    Application.Terminate;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you search Microsoft documentation, you can see that postmortem debugging can be controlled via registry key under \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542967(v=vs.85).aspx

You need to pay special attention if you want to manually change it.

Comment: What things do I need to pay special attention to?

Comment: "improper changes to the registry may render Windows unusable". All Microsoft debuggers have their own command line switch or option page to register themselves as postmortem debugger. Using this automatic way can avoid errors in registry editing. Not sure if Delphi also provides such automatic way.

Comment: So basically I should do it like this: 1. install each tool, note the registry settings, 2. install the next one. 3. goto 1; finally make a small switch app that sets the registry for the tool I want to use.

Comment: If you want that flexibility, then writing such a tool should help. Could not find an existing tool yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you really need to debug several concurrently running applications made with different tools - then the only option for you is to find or create a bridge JIT debugger, the one that would analyze which project crashed and relay the control to a corresponded IDE debugger

Comment: usually I know what will crash, so steps to change the JIT debugger by hand in combination with hints what to watch for will suffice.